# Why study Gal($\overline{\mathbb{Q}}|\mathbb{Q})$?

Tags: galois-theory, galois-representations

I was told by one of my teachers that Galois Representation is a major tool to study Gal($\overline{\mathbb{Q}}|\mathbb{Q}$). If we know this Galois group, what knid of questions can we answer ? In short, what motivated people to study this group ?

Comment: How is this question substantially different from the last question you asked?